# Why are singleton sets connected?

Tags: real-analysis, connectedness

Why are singleton sets connected? I know that a subset $S$ of a metric space $X$  is connected if and only if given subsets $U$ and $V$ of $X$:

i. $U$ and $V$ are open

ii. The intersection of $U$, $V$, and $S$ equals the empty set

iii. $S$ is a subset of the union of $U$ and $V$.

Comment: The question is rather: how could a singleton be [disconnected](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ConnectedSet.html)?

Comment: A set is disconnected if it can be split into two non-empty subsets in a certain way. You can’t split a singleton into two non-empty subsets at all.

Comment: Ah, I understand. So it is due to the fact that singleton sets can never be partitioned. More to the point, a singleton set can never be broken up into two distinct subsets whose intersection is the empty set and whose union is the original singleton set. Thanks for your help julien and Brian M. Scott.

Comment: If you read the definition of "disconnected" carefully, you'll see that a set must contain at least two points to be disconnected.  So any singelton is connected, as is the empty set.  Sorry if I'm duplicating what's above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because there exist no such sets U and V such that both $U\cap S\neq\emptyset$ and $V\cap S\neq\emptyset$.

A set $S$ is connected if there exist no open sets $U$ and $V$ such that $U\cap V\cap S=\emptyset$, $U\cap S\neq\emptyset$, $V\cap S\neq\emptyset$, and $S\subseteq U\cup V$.

Comment: How do you *know* that there exist no such sets? That is what the question asks you to prove.

Answer (score 0):

Recall that an open set $U$ in a metric space is open if and only if, given any $x$ in U there exists $\epsilon>0$ such that $N_\epsilon(x)$ is contained in $U$. The set $N_\epsilon(x)$ is the standard $\epsilon$-neighborhood of $x$.

Suppose that a singleton set in the metric space wasn't connected. Let $U=X-\{x_0\}$, that is the set of all points that aren't $x_0$. If a point $p$ is in $U$ then it is not $x_0$, so the distance between $p$ and $x_0$ is positive. Take $\epsilon>0$ to be less than this distance. What happens then?

This should be enough to convince yourself that singleton sets are connected.

Comment: Which definition of 'connected space' do we need to use to complete this proof? I was thinking about the usual definition of 'it cannot be partitioned into two disjoint open sets', but that doesn't seem to be related to your explanation so far.

Comment: @evaristegd That's exactly the point. The answers given are assuming the opposite. Suppose it was disconnected. Then you want to arrive at a contradiction. Mine was not a direct proof but rather a hint about **why** they have to be connected. Assuming the opposite you quickly contradict the reason why it should be connected. You end up working with neighborhoods (in my approach) or general sets in the metric space because you are working with the subspace topology. Try the proof yourself and see what you come up with! There are a few approaches (but all use the same logic).